# Other or different

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused about the words "other" and "different."

If I want to say that partner companies satisfy needs that differ from those I'm talking about in the text, what word is it better to use?

"Partner companies usually satisfy different needs."
"Partner companies usually satisfy other needs."

Answer (score 2):

Your first example can be interpreted to mean either:

*that partner companies satisfy needs different from those you have already mentioned*
or
*that partner companies satisfy various needs that differ from one another*.

Your second example means:

*that partner companies usually satisfy needs in addition to those you have already mentioned*.

In context, both are possible but **other** is more specific.

Comment: Thank you. And is it possible to say, "Partner companies usually satisfy different needs than our company?"

Comment: @Mila Yes, in context it's fine. It obviously requires background to make sense.